# Jquery datepicker validations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two text fields with jquery datepicker.

in the first field, if the date selected is greater than Today's date(current date). it should prompt a message to the user.

in the second field, the user has to select a date which is atleast 6 months greater than the current date. otherwise, it should prompt user with an alert message or whatever. i tried my best but unable to accomplish this. please help me out.

```
    $( "#issueDate" ).datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/date-picker.png",
          buttonImageOnly: false,
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          yearRange: '1950:2050',
          //maxDate:"0",
          buttonText:"Select Date",
          onSelect: function(selected) {

          }
        });

  $( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/date-picker.png",
              buttonImageOnly: false,
              dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
              buttonText:"Select Date",
              yearRange: '1950:2050',
              minDate:"+6M",
               onSelect: function(selected) {
                   var expiryDate = $(this).datepicker().val();
                   alert(expiryDate);


               }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

giving you idea

```
$( "#issueDate" ).datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/date-picker.png",
          buttonImageOnly: false,
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          yearRange: '1950:2050',
          //maxDate:"0",
          buttonText:"Select Date",
          minDate:new Date(),
          onclose: function(selected) {
                   $( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/date-picker.png",
              buttonImageOnly: false,
              dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
              buttonText:"Select Date",
              yearRange: '1950:2050',
              minDate:new Date($.datePicker.getDate()+ 6M)
               onSelect: function(selected) {
                   var expiryDate = $(this).datepicker().val();
                   alert(expiryDate);


               }
        });
          }
        });
```